# PyGtk3, How to Create "title-changed" signal for Gtk.Window Widget?

Tags: pygtk

i want create signal that runs when title of window changed.

example

```
def printTitleChanged(windowName):
    print("title of",windowName, "changed")

myWindow = gtk.Window("example")
myWindow.connect("title-changed", printTitleChanged, "myWindow")
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but the window title is out of reach from Python - it is managed by the window manager, except for setting and reading the title.

Also, normally only your program can change the title, so, if you want a callback when `set_title` is called, define a new method set_title which overrides the original `set_title`, and generate the callback yourself.

So: define a new class (eg. `My_window`) which inherits from Gtk's `GtkWindow`, and redefine `set_title`.

Comment: thanks for comment. i thought this. but users cannot use own handler so i want create like normal connect signal because users can connect too many handler.